# Without subqueries, SELECT all author_id's for authors with only empty posts

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | author_id | content |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 1  | 1         |         |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 2  | 2         |         |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 3  | 1         |         |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 4  | 2         | XYZ     |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

How would I select a list of `author_id`s who have only posts with no content, without using subqueries? In this case, I would want a query that would just return `author_id` 1.

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way without having to use sub-queries for the sake of performance.

```
SELECT author_id
FROM my_table
WHERE author_id NOT IN (
    SELECT author_id FROM my_table WHERE content != ''
)
GROUP BY author_id
```

Here's [a fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZ3tMZZZW7MfdVbVseTSSx/0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could filter the groups using a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT author_id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY author_id
HAVING MAX(LENGTH(content)) = 0
```

Or you could use a JOIN to try to find any row with a non-blank content and only select those that have no match.

```
SELECT t1.author_id
FROM my_table AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table AS t2 ON t1.author_id = t2.author_id
  AND LENGTH(t2.content) > 0
WHERE t2.author_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I was editing my answer to add the second solution simultaneously as @Nick posted his answer. His is better, because it can use an index on (author_id, content) if you have such an index.

Comment: Cool! Is either of these options objectively better? I kind of like the simplicity of the first example here.

Comment: Depends on how many rows you expect to match. Since it depends on your data, you should try both and see which one performs better for your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self join, `JOIN`ing authors to themselves where they have content in an article, and then selecting only the authors that have no content:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1.author_id
FROM my_table m1
LEFT JOIN my_table m2 ON m2.author_id = m1.author_id AND m2.content != ''
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
author_id
1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phNjjecxKESdCENUgJPVDy/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT author_id
FROM my_table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
           (SELECT NULL
            FROM my_table b
            WHERE a.author_id = b.author_id
            AND b.content != '')
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that comment in the OP. OTOH, both the join and subquery can use the indexes effectively. I expect the explain plan and performance to be same in all the provided answers. The only exception being the `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause.